# Creating JSON Objects in Node.js loop - Node stops on undefined object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Inside my loop I am creating JSON objects like so

```
JSONObject = {
   "manufacturer": JSON.parse(object.deviceSpecificationJson[0]).manufacturer,
   "model": JSON.parse(object.deviceSpecificationJson[0]).model,
   "capacity": object.capacity[0],
   // etc
}
```

But node throws an error when capcity is undefined, some of the devices in my XML which I converted to json may not contain a value in the capacity field.

How do I tell node to keep going even if the field is undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can use the ternary operator on `object.capacity`, like so:
`object.capacity ? object.capacity[0] : null`. This checks whether `object.capacity` exists, and executes the line after `?` if it does, and executes the line after `:` if it does not.

More generally, this is how you use the ternary operator, `{condition} ? {if true} : {otherwise}`

An alternative would be to define a function that checks for `object.capacity` and returns `null` or whatever default value you want the object property to have if it does not exist.

I have modified your example with the changes below:

```js
JSONObject = {
    "manufacturer": JSON.parse(object.deviceSpecificationJson[0]).manufacturer,
    "model": JSON.parse(object.deviceSpecificationJson[0]).model,
    "capacity": object.capacity ? object.capacity[0] : null,
    // null can be replaced with the value you want it to show if the property does not exist
    // like 0, or an empty string ''
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put one condition to check `undefined`

```
JSONObject = {
  "manufacturer": JSON.parse(object.deviceSpecificationJson[0]).manufacturer,
  "model": JSON.parse(object.deviceSpecificationJson[0]).model,
  "capacity": object.capacity[0]!= undefined ? object.capacity[0]: 'your static value for undefined capacity like null' ,
  // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally add `capacity` to your `JSONObject` like so:

```
JSONObject = {
   "manufacturer": JSON.parse(object.deviceSpecificationJson[0]).manufacturer,
   "model": JSON.parse(object.deviceSpecificationJson[0]).model,
   // etc
}
if(object.capacity[0]) JSONObject["capacity"] = object.capacity[0]
```

Or, if you just want to set the `capacity` to be `0GB` if it doesn't exist you can do the following:

```
JSONObject = {
   "manufacturer": JSON.parse(object.deviceSpecificationJson[0]).manufacturer,
   "model": JSON.parse(object.deviceSpecificationJson[0]).model,
   "capacity": object.capacity[0] || '0GB',
   // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way i can think of is to use `&& and ||`

```
JSONObject = {
   "manufacturer": JSON.parse(object.deviceSpecificationJson[0]).manufacturer,
   "model": JSON.parse(object.deviceSpecificationJson[0]).model,
   "capacity": (object && object.capacity[0]) || 'value in case object.capacity is undefined',
   // etc
}
```

Comment: its a string inside an array such as '32GB', the error I get is TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined and node exits. I don't understand why you put `(object && object.capacity[0])` what is the `object &&` part for?

Comment: `object &&` checks for the object existence. so if `object` is a falsy value than the `object.capacity[0]` will not be executed

Comment: If the object was named differently like `result.capacity[0]` would it then be `(result && result.capacity[0])`

Comment: @Scott yes. it is called `short circuiting` which is same as logical and gate. where if any of the input is false output turns out to be false. irrespective of other input

Comment: I tried `"storageSize": (product && product.vertical[0].storageSize[0]) || ""` and got the same error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` ?